# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: EMPTY?

Tags: python, flask

Any suggestion toward a clean solution will be appreciated.

I am trying to add some static files to an existing app, a static folder with other files is already set. I would like to define several routes based on a list, the goal is to be able to easily add files.

The problem is that I receive this instead of a working program, the "endpoint function" isn't properly detected.

Output:

```
 {'/file1.js': <function func at 0x10aedfed8>, '/file2.js': <function func at 0x10aeea050>}
 {'/file1.js': <function func at 0x10aedfed8>, '/file2.js': <function func at 0x10aeea050>}
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "flaskweird.py", line 29, in <module>
     app.add_url_rule(d, '', app.serv_deps[d])
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 62, in wrapper_func
     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 984, in add_url_rule
'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
 AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function:
```

Code :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

def gen_serv_dep(path):
    fp = 'ui' + path  # path always starts with /
    with open(fp) as f:
        content = f.read()
    if path.endswith('.css'):
        mime = "text/css"
    elif path.endswith('.js'):
        mime = "text/javascript"
    else:
        mime = "text"
    def func():
        #this.__name__ = path  # doesn't change anything
        return Response(response=content, status=200, mimetype=mime)
    return func

deps = ['/file1.js', '/file2.js']
app.serv_deps = {}
for d in deps:
    app.serv_deps[d] = gen_serv_dep(d)
for d in deps:
    print(app.serv_deps)
app.add_url_rule(d, '', app.serv_deps[d])

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Sample files to serve:

```
mkdir ui
echo "test1" > ui/file1.js
echo "test2" > ui/file2.js
```

Flask==0.10.1

Comment: Have you considered using Flask's ["blueprint"](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/blueprints/) to introduce additional sources of static files?

Comment: Uhm... Thanks, looks like that could work, I'll try. Any idea why the supposedly overridden function name is empty?

Answer (score 0):

"Because you passed an empty string to `add_url_rule` multiple times in a for loop. Pick a unique name each time." -- davidism

This works fine

```
for d in deps:
    app.add_url_rule(d, d, app.serv_deps[d])
```

Thanks